# EF6 cascade object very slow to setup

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have a problem with entity framework, when trying to retreive data.
I split the work into multiple steps:

1. generate the query
2. Execute it and retreive dataset from db.
3. Fill in my ViewModel using dataset.

Actualy, step 1 and 2 are very fast, step 3 can take up to 1 minute (for 200 records). Meaning it's not SQL related (i copied query from debugger to MSSMS, and it's executed in less than a second).
First i was using step 3B, to make it simple, i retreive a `Job` entity which i transform into a `MapMarker` object. and i thaught it was the `ConvertAll` that was slowing down the process.

After some SO reading, I tested using Select but result was the same.
The only this is, if i use the "main object", in this example: Job, everything is fast; as a test, i put the Job.Job_ID into all field, and the execution time is normal (less than a second).
Then i insert again this: `,Latitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Latitude.Value` and the slowlyness is back.

I even tried step 3C using a foreach loop (which i knew was not better but ok...) but it is as slow as other solutions.

The main question is:
**What am i missing in the EF6 configuration (or somewhere else ?) that make this process so slow ?**

I'm going to do it the good old way and execute my own sql query, i started using EF, i guess these entities should be usable, for now using "simple" objects works realy fine but if you cannot cascade them.. what is the added value ?

Below the steps i'm talking about.

Step 1:

```
IEnumerable<Job> Jobs = db.Job.Include(e => e.Maintenance.MaintenancePlan.MaintenanceType).Include(e => e.Maintenance.MaintenancePlan.MaintenanceType)
                .Include(e => e.Maintenance.MaintenancePlan.MaintenanceType.Shape)
                .Include(e => e.Maintenance.MaintenanceStatus)
                .Include(e => e.Users)
                .Include(e => e.Users.Color)
                .Include(e => e.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS);
```

Step 2:

```
List<Job> listJobs = Jobs.ToList();
```

Step 3A:

```
IEnumerable<MapMarker> IEMarkerJobsA = Jobs.AsEnumerable().Select(_Job => new MapMarker
            {
                ID = string.Format("Job_{0}", _Job.Job_ID)
                ,Latitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Latitude.Value
                ,Longitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Longitude.Value
                });
            List<MapMarker> listMarkerJobsA = IEMarkerJobsA.ToList();
```

Step 3B:

IEnumerable listMarkerJobs = listJobs.ConvertAll(
            new Converter(MapMarker.MapMarkerFactory));
When the Factory is like this:

```
public static MapMarker MapMarkerFactory(Job _Job)
    {


        MapMarker A = new MapMarker();
        A.ID = String.Format("Job_{0}", _Job.Job_ID);
        A.Latitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Latitude.Value;
        A.Longitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Longitude.Value;
        A.Title = String.Format("{1}", (_Job.Users != null) ? String.Format("[{0}]", _Job.Users.Users_NickName) : "", _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Equipement_Name);
        A.Icon = GetIconePath((_Job.Users != null) ? _Job.Users.Color.Color_Name : "red", _Job.Maintenance.MaintenancePlan.MaintenanceType.Shape.Shape_Name, _Job.Maintenance.MaintenanceStatus.MaintenanceStatus_Description, "13px");
        A.IconSize = new Size(13, 13);
        A.WindowInfoContent = String.Format("JobID= {0}", _Job.Job_ID);
        return A;
    }
```

Step 3C:

```
List<MapMarker> listMarkerJobs = new List<MapMarker>();
            foreach (Job _Job in Jobs)
            {
                MapMarker A = new MapMarker();
                A.ID = String.Format("Job_{0}", _Job.Job_ID);
                A.Latitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Latitude.Value:
                A.Longitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Longitude.Value;
                A.Title = String.Format("{1}", (_Job.Users != null) ? String.Format("[{0}]", _Job.Users.Users_NickName) : "", _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Equipement_Name);
                A.Icon = MapMarker.GetIconePath((_Job.Users != null) ? _Job.Users.Color.Color_Name : "red", _Job.Maintenance.MaintenancePlan.MaintenanceType.Shape.Shape_Name, _Job.Maintenance.MaintenanceStatus.MaintenanceStatus_Description, "13px");
                A.IconSize = new System.Drawing.Size(13, 13);
                A.WindowInfoContent = String.Format("JobID= {0}", _Job.Job_ID);
                listMarkerJobs.Add(A);
            }
```

Comment: I believe you have N+1 issue somewhere in your code, try profiling SQL queries that are generated by EF to see if you forgot to include some table to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for part 3

```
List<MapMarker> listMarkerJobs = Jobs.AsNoTracking().Select(_Job => new MapMarker
{
    ID = string.Format("Job_{0}", _Job.Job_ID),
    Latitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Latitude.Value,
    Longitude = _Job.Maintenance.Equipement.Location.GPS.GPS_Longitude.Value
}).ToList();
```